# Windows Phone 8.1 Battery Info

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

Hi i need  functionality for my Windows phone 8.1 winrt app (javascript).
1. API to detect when a device is under charging
2. API to detect battery percentage under a certain limit.

Answer (score 2):

There is no actual way to see if battery is charging but you can use the following code:

```
Debug.WriteLineIf(Battery.GetDefault().RemainingDischargeTime > TimeSpan.FromDays(5),"Battery is charging");
```

In order to check battery level all you need to do is the following:

```
Debug.WriteLine(Battery.GetDefault().RemainingChargePercent.ToString() + "% Battery is remiaining");
```

Comment: I mentioned in the OP that im using javascript.